# Override post requests

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, http-post

I have this code that I put in my console:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(body) {
    // modifies inputted request
    newBody = JSON.parse(body);
    newBody.points = 417;

  // sends modified request
    this.realSend(JSON.stringify(newBody));
}
```

It is supposed to make the points 417 every time it sends a request, but when I look at the request body, it still says the original amount of points. Any help?

Comment: This part looks ok

Comment: Where do you see the request you have sent? And how did you save the original `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send` that you obviously use later with `this.realSend(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add an `alert()` or `console.log()` into your modified `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send` to check if it actually works. There is a way to prevent this kind of modifications silently.

Comment: The alert never shows up, what am I doing wrong? Maybe the website uses fetch instead? I honestly don't know, since I'm new to all this request stuff.

Comment: There is no guaranty, that you will get what you want with `fetch`, though you can try it. If it's not your website, then there might be many different tricks, because there are many ways to send post requests

Comment: Yea, its not my website.

Answer (score 2):

If your function is not being called, possible `fetch` is used to make ajax requests.

So you can wrap both functions, like this

```
const send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
const _fetch = window.fetch;

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (body) {
   const newBody = JSON.parse(body);
   newBody.points = 417;
   send.call(this, JSON.stringify(newBody));
};

window.fetch = function(url, options){
   let newBody;
   if(options.body) {
      newBody = JSON.parse(options.body);
      newBody.points = 417;
      options.body = JSON.stringify(newBody);
   }
   _fetch.call(this, url, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the error you are experiencing is hard to diagnose exactly without seeing how you created `this.realSend`.

However, this code will work:

```
const send = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function (body) {
    const newBody = JSON.parse(body);
    newBody.points = 417;
    send.call(this, JSON.stringify(newBody));
};
```

Note that instead of storing the original `send` method on `XMLHttpRequest.prototype`, I've kept in a separate variable and simply invoked it with the correct `this` value through `send.call()`. This seems like a cleaner implementation with less chance for conflicts with other code.

See [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/override-xmlhttprequest-methods-n4unm?file=/src/index.js:204-473) for a working example.